# Is user (outside of domain) part of active directory group

Tags: c#

In C#, I'm trying to authenticate a user against a group in ActiveDirectory. The code below works fine for users within our domain, but we also have users in other countries that log in to our vpn and need to access my program. The code below crashes when they attempt to run it. I've tried everything and I just can't figure this out.

```
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.Name, "myGroup")
var members = groupPrincipal.GetMembers(true).ToList()
var isMember = members.Any(m => m.Guid == userPrincipal.Guid)
```

How can I test to see if a user is part of an Active Directory group that is outside of our domain?

Thankx

Answer (score 0):

Are the VPN users authenticating against the domain?  Also, how are you getting the userPrincipal?

Here's some code that tackles the problem from the other side.  It's a little older but I used it to verify users could run a small program of mine.

```
var userGroups = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups;

foreach (var domainGroup in userGroups)
{
    var group = domainGroup.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));

    if (group.Value == "domain\\myGroup")
    {
        isMember = true;
    }
}
```

Of course you can translate that into the appropriate linq statement if need be.